# Centos Vm on Virtualbox doesn't know network interfaces

Tags: linux, networking, virtualbox, virtual-machine, centos

I'm trying to use a **Centos Vm** imported in Virtual boxes.The host machine is also Ubuntu.
The problem is that I've configured **Virtual box** network adapters and  I've tested all interface types in my Vm too but it doesn't show any interface except `lo` for `loop back` when I use `ifconfig`. And so I can't access the host network and it's internet connection too.

I've searched allot and I really don't know what's the problem.can anyone help me?

Comment: What about `ifconfig -a`?

Comment: **ifconfig -a** shows eth2 but it doesn't show up when i use **ifconfig**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using Centos 7 you can use :

```
nmcli device status
```

You will get somthing like :

```
PÉRIPHÉRIQUE  TYPE      ÉTAT        CONNECTION
enp0s3        ethernet  connecté    eth0
enp0s8        ethernet  déconnecté  --
lo            loopback  non-géré    --
```

And add a connection where `eth0` is random name and `enp0s3` is the name of your device :

```
nmcli connection add  con-name "eth0" ifname enp0s3 autoconnect yes type ethernet ip4 192.168.56.30/24 gw4 192.168.56.1

nmcli connection up eth0
```

If you want the `dhcp` to handle the ip@ just remove the ips from the command above.

In case you're using centos 6 :

```
vi /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0

TYPE=Ethernet
BOOTPROTO=staic {dhcp}
DEVICE=eth0
ONBOOT=yes
HWADDR=08:00:27:D4:00:84 {your mac address}
TYPE=Ethernet
UUID=f308b97f-3cea-45fd-9a82-861ec9151d20
ONBOOT=yes
#if static uncomment the following 
#IPADDR=192.168.56.20
#NETMASK=255.255.255.0
#NETWORK=192.168.56.0
#GETWAY=192.168.56.1
```

PS : Each file "ifcfg-eth*" represent a connection.

Comment: I'm using **Centos 6.4**.Is it work on this version too??

Comment: Yes, Follow from "In case you're using centos 6 :........."